# Serializing object with Borsh-go

Tags: nearprotocol

I am trying to serialize near transaction action using `borsh-go`. It fails unexpectedly.

```golang
type Action struct {
    Enum     borsh.Enum `borsh_enum:"true"`
    Transfer Transfer
}

type Transfer struct {
    Deposit big.Int
}

action := Action{
            Enum:     3,
            Transfer: Transfer{Deposit: *big.NewInt(1)},
        }
fmt.Println(borsh.Serialize(action))
```

output: `[3] complex enum too large`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know GO nor Rust well enough to give an answer, but here are some examples on how to use borsh-go https://github.com/near/borsh-go/blob/master/README.md